# Drag object in unity 2d with moving camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to drag my 2d object in `unity2d` using code with:

```
offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new 

Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
```

Problem is that my camera is also moving along x axis so when I click on `gameobject` to drag it, it moves along x axis. I want to make this `gameobejct` static so it will be in its place and won't move? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using absolute screen-centric position, you can try using the speed of the mouse pointer. Something like:

```
if(beingDragged) {
    transform.position += new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"),
            Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), 0);
}
```

Another option is to use a variable to track the camera's movement *since the start of the drag*. Then you can subtract this movement offset from your calculation, so that the dragging is done in "World Space" rather than "Screen Space"

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't implement your suggestion. Here is the code for dragging the object, when OnMouseDown() it always gets the position of moving camera. Here is code above

Comment: What I'm saying is to *ignore* the coordinates you get from `Input.mousePosition` and don't use `ScreenToWorldPoint`. Instead, if you use the `Input.GetAxis` method for "Mouse X" and "Mouse Y", you'll get access to the distance the mouse has moved since the previous frame. If you base your drag movement on *only* those values, the drag movement will be based entirely on mouse movement and not be affected by the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I couldn't implement your suggestion. Here is the code for dragging the object, when OnMouseDown()    it always gets the position of moving camera.

```
void OnMouseDown()

   {

    screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
    offset = gameObject.transform.position + Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{ 
    Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(screenPoint.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);

    Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (curScreenPoint);
    transform.position = curPosition;

}
```

}